# how to add a border around UL tabs without disrupting the design

Tags: html, css, outline

This is how it looks now:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

```css
.k-tabstrip-top>.k-tabstrip-items>.k-item {
  border-bottom: none;
}

div#tabstrip-1 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}

div#tabstrip-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  border: none;
}

.tabstrip {
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-item.k-state-default {
  padding: 0px !important;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px !important;
  margin-right: 3px !important;
}

.k-item.k-state-hover[role=tab] {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.k-tabstrip-items {
  background: transparent !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  width: fit-content;
}

.k-tabstrip-items .k-item {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

span.k-link {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* Transparentnost barstripa*/

.k-content,
.k-panel>li.k-item,
.k-panelbar>li.k-item,
.k-tiles {
  background-color: transparent;
}

li.k-item span {
  color: white !important;
}

.k-layer {
  width: 100% !important;
}

li.k-state-active {
  transform: scale(1.05)
}

#carouselExampleControls {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*  1st button */

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-item.k-state-default.k-last>span {
  background-color: var(--imenaColor) !important;
  background-color: var(--imenaColorRGBA) !important;
  color: white !important;
}

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-state-active.k-state-active.k-last>span {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: var(--imenaColor) !important;
  color: var(--imenaColorRGBA) !important;
}


/* 2st button */

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-item.k-state-default.k-first>span {
  background-color: var(--imenaColor) !important;
  background-color: var(--imenaColorRGBA) !important;
  color: white !important;
}

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-state-active.k-state-active.k-first>span {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: var(--imenaColor) !important;
  color: var(--imenaColorRGBA) !important;
}

#tabstrip>ul>li.k-state-active {
  top: 1px;
}

.k-tabstrip .k-tabstrip-items .k-link {
  padding: 10px 20px 5px 20px !important;
}

.ConfTime {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="k-reset k-tabstrip-items">
  <li class="k-item k-state-default k-state-active k-tab-on-top k-first" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabstrip-1"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span class="k-link" unselectable="on">Names</span></li>
  <li class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="tab" aria-controls="tabstrip-2"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span class="k-link" unselectable="on">Birthdays</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: I added full CSS for tabs, to easily reproduce the error. The stylesheet is not originally mine (I took over), so I might have overlooked a style, thus unable to fix the error. The stylesheet is not originally mine (I took over), so I might have overlooked a style, thus unable to fix the error.

New code added ->. I hope it's enough information:

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the issue. Please provide all css pertaining to the tab styling.

Comment: I've edited the question, added the css.

Comment: Your code is not enough to find the error. Click on "Run code snippet" and see the design what you added in code area.